# VBA Excel to PPT export

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I'm trying to transfer some code from one workbook to another and I'm having trouble figuring out why it's not working. I transferred the sheets into the new workbook and made the necessary updates in the code to reference the correct sheets. Everything else between the workbooks is consistent, but I keep receiving a compile error : User-defined type not defined. I tried debugging but I'm not sure what it's pointing to. Thanks in advance.

```
Sub CreatePP()

    Dim ppApp       As Object
    Dim ppSlide     As Object

    On Error Resume Next
    Set ppApp = GetObject(, "Powerpoint.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If ppApp Is Nothing Then
        Set ppApp = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")
        ppApp.Visible = True
        ppApp.Presentations.Add
    End If


    Dim MySheets, i As Long

    MySheets = Array(Sheet44, Sheet45, Sheet46, Sheet47, Sheet43, Sheet42, Sheet41, Sheet40, Sheet48)  'these are sheet codenames not sheet name.
    MyRanges = Array("A1:Q45", "A1:Q45", "A1:Q45", "A1:Q45", "A1:Q45", "A1:Q45", "A1:Q45", "A1:Q45", "A1:Q45")

    For i = LBound(MySheets) To UBound(MySheets)
        If ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count = 0 Then
            Set ppSlide = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12) 'ppLayoutBlank
        Else
            ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Add ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count + 1, 12
            Set ppSlide = ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides(ppApp.ActivePresentation.Slides.Count)
        End If
        Copy_Paste_to_PowerPoint ppApp, ppSlide, MySheets(i), MySheets(i).Range(MyRanges(i)), xl_Bitmap
    Next




End Sub


Sub Copy_Paste_to_PowerPoint(ByRef ppApp As Object, ByRef ppSlide As Object, ByVal ObjectSheet As Worksheet, _
                                    ByRef PasteObject As Object, Optional ByVal Paste_Type As PasteFormat)


    Dim PasteRange      As Boolean
    Dim objChart        As ChartObject
    Dim lngSU           As Long

    Select Case TypeName(PasteObject)
        Case "Range"
            If Not TypeName(Selection) = "Range" Then Application.GoTo PasteObject.Cells(1)
            PasteRange = True
        Case "Chart": Set objChart = PasteObject.Parent
        Case "ChartObject": Set objChart = PasteObject
        Case Else
            MsgBox PasteObject.Name & " is not a valid object to paste. Macro will exit", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
    End Select

    With Application
        lngSU = .ScreenUpdating
        .ScreenUpdating = 0
    End With

    ppApp.ActiveWindow.View.GotoSlide ppSlide.SlideNumber

    On Error GoTo -1: On Error GoTo 0
    DoEvents

    If PasteRange Then
        If Paste_Type = xl_Bitmap Then
            '//Paste Range as Picture
            PasteObject.CopyPicture Appearance:=1, Format:=-4147
            ppSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
        ElseIf Paste_Type = xl_HTML Then
            '//Paste Range as HTML
            PasteObject.Copy
            ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(8, link:=1).Select  'ppPasteHTML
        ElseIf Paste_Type = xl_Link Then
            '//Paste Range as Linked
            PasteObject.Copy
            ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(0, link:=1).Select   'ppPasteDefault
        End If
    Else
        If Paste_Type = xl_Link Then
            '//Copy & Paste Chart Linked
            objChart.Chart.ChartArea.Copy
            ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(link:=True).Select
        Else
            '//Copy & Paste Chart Not Linked
            objChart.Chart.CopyPicture Appearance:=1, Size:=1, Format:=2
            ppSlide.Shapes.Paste.Select
        End If
    End If

    '//Center pasted object in the slide
    With ppApp.ActiveWindow
        If .Height > .Selection.ShapeRange.Height Then
            .Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = True
            .Selection.ShapeRange.Height = .Height * 0.82
        End If
        If .Selection.ShapeRange.Width > 708 Then
            .Selection.ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = True
            .Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 708
        End If
        .Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignCenters, True
        .Selection.ShapeRange.Align msoAlignMiddles, True
    End With

    With Application
        .CutCopyMode = False
        .ScreenUpdating = lngSU
    End With

    'AppActivate ("Microsoft Excel")

End Sub
```

Comment: `Optional ByVal Paste_Type As PasteFormat` I can't find a variable type called `PasteFormat`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copied that Copy_Paste_to_PowerPoint function you forgot to copy the enum.

```
Public Enum PasteFormat
    xl_Link = 0
    xl_HTML = 1
    xl_Bitmap = 2
End Enum
```

Did you get it from somewhere like [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/686767-visual-basic-applications-excel-range-copied-high-resolution-power-point-slide.html)? It looks a bit like that version. It looks like you or whoever you got that from stripped out the attribution. You really should put a comment attributing the source of your snippets in there. Not only is it a legal requirement of places like stackoverflow, but it's also quite useful for figuring out what code does, where it came from, and what might be wrong with it.

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry about that, I didn't compile the original code, I wasn't sure where it was taken from.